# Toast.getText Not Showing Called From Button's OnClickListener in Activity Class Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-toast

I know this has probably been asked a million times, and I have searched.  this question originally started from my wanting to have an activity with some buttons and when one was clicked before sending over to the next activity check for null variables and if some where found show a toast.  I have since for bug checking removed the null variable checking segment to just show the variables.  A very barebones and simplified code of the situation is like so

```
public Class MyClass extends Activity {

EditText et1;
EditText et2;
Button btn1;
String et1string;
String et2string;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                et1string = et1.getText().toString();
                et2string = et2.getText().toString();
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "et1string =" + et1string + " and et2string =" + et2string);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "et1string =" + et1string + " and et2string =" + et2string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
     });
}
```

I have tried using the following in place of the Toast.makeText

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "et1string =" + et1string + " and et2string =" + et2string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                });
```

Either way there is no toast message that is shown.

I am sure i am doing something easily noticed by a guru, but just has me puzzled.  the logcat shows the logd, and this isnt application dependant, I would just like to figure out why i cant get a toast to show up

Also Ive read that notifications can be disabled?  idk, but I am programming with the version 23 sdk so if there is a permissions i need to ask for some guidance on that would be great

Answer (score 2):

You have to call show on your toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "et1string =" + et1string + " and et2string =" + et2string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: see im an idiot thanks, kidding on the idiot, but you gotta learn somehow right?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to `.show()`.

This should show up as a warning in Android Studio, but if it isn't, go to your Preferences > Inspections, and make sure that the "Toast created but not shown" inspection is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

add a ".show" at the end.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "et1string =" + et1string + " and et2string =" + et2string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question — solved by calling `show()` — was already answered, but I feel this is a great opportunity to share [Reto Meier's awesome post](https://medium.com/google-developers/writing-more-code-by-writing-less-code-with-android-studio-live-templates-244f648d17c7) where he talks about Android Studio's Live Templates and he talks about this very Toast issue.